# Should Humor and Jokes tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I was surprised to learn that [humor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor) and [jokes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jokes) were not synonyms.

### [Humor](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/humor/info)

> Questions about humorous expressions, jokes, puns, etc.

38 questions

### [Jokes](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/jokes/info)

> For questions about jokes. But be careful, many joke questions are considered [off-topic](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/are-questions-about-ununderstood-english-language-jokes-on-topic) and will be closed.

44 questions

Also interesting is that there are only 5 questions tagged with both.

Glancing through the list, there doesn't seem to be a noticeable topical difference between the two tags. I propose that the jokes tag be made a synonym of the broader humor tag.

Thanks to Howard's comment, I also noticed that there was the [pun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pun) tag.

### [Pun](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/pun/info)

> A pun is a joke exploiting the different possible meanings of a word or the fact that there are words that sound alike but have different meanings.

33 questions

[Pun **x** Jokes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pun+jokes): 4 tagged questions

[Pun **x** Humor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pun+humor): 3 tagged questions

There are no questions with all 3 tags.

I personally think Pun is an appropriate tag because it's a type of humor that relies upon a facet of the english language. As the jokes tag points out via the linked meta question, questions about jokes that *don't* rely on the English Language are off topic. For that reason, I think Jokes and Humor should be synonym, as they are both fairly generic terms for 'funny stuff'. More to the point, the nuance between Humor and Joke does not depend on the English language.

Comment: Are tag-synonym requests feature requests? Apologies if I got it wrong. Also, I would be happy to go on a retagging spree, but all my retags would just end up in the edit-queue...

Comment: Is this question a humorous joke? ;-P  I'm surprised you were surprised that humor and jokes are not synonyms. Many things, like my wayward cat, can be humorous without involving a joke - although my cat might tell you otherwise when I attempt to make a joke about my cat.  Sure, a joke could be considered a subset of humor, but something, as perhaps your question, might not be a joke or even a laughing matter. Is this a joke? No I'm serious - or am I being sarcastic?  If the latter, then we'd have to make jokes a subset of "Sarcasm" if there is such a tag. Then we have a problem ... :))